# Eloquent query builder got 'BadMethodCallException' when use an attribute of an object as input to where statement

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, illuminate

I use Eloquent PHP as ORM and implement query builder for my web applications.

Usually, it works when the code looks like this.

```
$builder = Area::query()->limit(30);

if ($subDistrictCode = $request->getParam('sub_district_code')) {
    $builder->where('sub_district_code', $subDistrictCode);
}

if ($districtCode = $request->getParam('district_code')) {
    $builder->where('district_code', $districtCode);
}

$areasCount = $builder->count();

if ($limit = $request->getParam('length')) {
    $builder->limit($limit);
}

if ($offset = $request->getParam('start')) {
    $builder->offset($offset);
}

$areas = $builder->orderBy('province','ASC')->get();
```

But when I use an attribute from an object I got this error:

Call to undefined method Erdkk\Models\Areas::getIdAttribute()

The code looks like this.

```
$builder = Area::query()->limit(30);

if ($subDistrictCode = $request->getParam('sub_district_code')) {
    $builder->where('sub_district_code', $subDistrictCode['id']);
}

if ($districtCode = $request->getParam('district_code')) {
    $builder->where('district_code', $districtCode);
}

$areasCount = $builder->count();

if ($limit = $request->getParam('length')) {
    $builder->limit($limit);
}

if ($offset = $request->getParam('start')) {
    $builder->offset($offset);
}

$areas = $builder->orderBy('province','ASC')->get();
```

Comment: Can you share a dd of the $subDistrictCode?

Comment: ```
$subDistrictCode = {
    id: 12345
}
```

Comment: That looks strange to me, but looks most like a json string. You need to decode ( `json_decode($subDistrictCode)` ) it first.

Comment: i checked the data type is integer, so already decoded

Comment: You accessed the id as you would access the id key of an array. `dd`ing an array would produce this: `array:1 [ "id" => 12345 ]`. And `dd`ing a json encoded array would produce: `"{"id":12345}"` So, what do you mean it is an integer?